# How to verify information using standard linux/unix filters?

Tags: bash

I have the following data in a Tab delimited file:

_ *DATA* _

```
Col1    Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5
blah1   blah2     blah3   4       someotherText
blahA   blahZ     blahJ   2       someotherText1
blahB   blahT     blahT   7       someotherText2
blahC   blahQ     blahL   10      someotherText3
```

I want to make sure that the data in 4th column of this file is always an integer.  I know how to do this in perl

- Read each line, Store value of 4th column in a variable
- check if that variable is an integer
- if above is true, continue the loop
- else break out of the loop with message saying file data not correct

But how would I do this in a shell script using standard linux/unix filter? My guess would be to use grep, but I am not sure how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cut -f4 data | LANG=C grep -q '[^0-9]' && echo invalid
```

- LANG=C for speed
- -q to quit at first error in possible long file

If you need to strip the first line then use tail -n+2 or you could get hacky and use:

```
cut -f4 data | LANG=C sed -n '1b;/[^0-9]/{s/.*/invalid/p;q}'
```

Comment: This is your best bet if your validation is always going to be nice and simple - less overhead than using awk. If your validation is more complex than a single-column integer check, have a look at my answer. An awk script will be more easily extended.

Comment: @pixelbeat: on running on the data, prints invalid. im not sure why one liner does not work. did you run it on the data?

Comment: It's reporting invalid because the first line needs to be skipped. Also, love the sed hack.

Comment: In the first version above (with `grep`), you can change the `-q` to `-n` and it will print the line number and data value as well as the text "invalid".

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is the tool most naturally suited for parsing by columns:

```
awk '{if ($4 !~ /^[0-9]+$/) { print "Error! Column 4 is not an integer:"; print $0; exit 1}}' data.txt
```

As you get more complex with your error detection, you'll probably want to put the awk script in a file and invoke it with `awk -f verify.awk data.txt`.

Edit: in the form you'd put into verify.awk:

```
{
    if ($4 !~/^[0-9]+$/)  {
        print "Error! Column 4 is not an integer:"
        print $0
        exit 1
    }
}
```

Note that I've made awk exit with a non-zero code, so that you can easily check it in your calling script with something like this in bash:

```
if awk -f verify.awk data.txt; then
     # action for success
else
     # action for failure
fi
```

You could use grep, but it doesn't inherently recognize columns. You'd be stuck writing patterns to match the columns.

Comment: Your script quits on the first failure, so it doesn't report subsequent ones. Also, it misses values like 2.2, 2a and a2

Comment: I thought the *point* was to exit on the first failure. If you don't want it to, set a flag instead of exiting, and add `END {if (error_flag) {exit 1}}` to the end. I edited the regex to fix the other problem. (I was for some reason thinking it was a whole-line match)

Answer (score 1):

Edited....

```
#!/bin/bash

isdigit ()
{
    [ $# -eq 1 ] || return 0

    case $1 in
        *[!0-9]*|"") return 0;;
        *) return 1;;
    esac
}

while read line
do
    col=($line)
    digit=${col[3]}

    if isdigit "$digit"
    then
        echo "err, no digit $digit"
    else
        echo "hey, we got a digit $digit"
    fi
done
```

Use this in a script foo.sh  and run it like ./foo.sh < data.txt

See [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testbranch.html) for more info

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. It's for checking if a given string is an integer, not for looking within a file, especially not the fourth column of it.

Comment: That's going to be slower than a slow thing.
The golden rule is do as little in shell as possible

Comment: Not to start a religious war, but IMHO using bash alone is better than using a mix to awk,cut..etc.. 
You don't have the startup time/overhead for the shell to launch another external program... bash just uses its built in language this way.

Answer (score 1):

[awk](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk.html) is what you need.

I can't upvote yet, but I would upvote Jefromi's answer if I could.

Comment: I think awk is a little overkill for this.
The standard functional tools of cut & grep suffice and will probably be faster

Comment: awk is defintiely not overkill. on the contrary, using 2 or more tools through chaining to do a simple task like that is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need it BASH only, because tr, cut & awk behave differently on Linux/Solaris/Aix/BSD/etc:

```
while read a b c d e ;  do [[ "$d" =~ ^[0-9] ]] || echo "$a: $d not a numer" ;  done < data
```

Comment: So, you’re worried about the portability of *tr*, *cut*, and *awk*, and to get around that you’re using *bash*, eh?

Comment: `tr` and `awk` definitely both have POSIX standards -- not sure about `cut`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
linenum=1; while read line; do field=($line); if ((linenum>1)); then [[ ! ${field[3]} =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo "FAIL: line number: ${linenum}, value: '${field[3]}' is not an integer"; fi; ((linenum++)); done < data.txt
```

To stop at the first error, add a `break`:

```
linenum=1; while read line; do field=($line); if ((linenum>1)); then [[ ! ${field[3]} =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && echo "FAIL: line number: ${linenum}, value: '${field[3]}' is not an integer" && break; fi; ((linenum++)); done < data.txt
```

Comment: Over twice as fast as **pixelbeat's** answer on my system.

Comment: ...for small files. I did a test on a larger file and **pixelbeat's** answer, well, **beat** mine by a wide margin. However, mine tells you what line the error is on.

Comment: @Dennis: I wanted an answer using standard unix/linux filters

Answer (score 0):

```
cut -f 4 filename
```

will return the fourth field of each line to stdout.

Hopefully that's a good start, because it's been a long time since I had to do any major shell scripting.

Comment: Yes, you could do something like `cut -f 4 <file> | egrep -v '^[0-9]+$'`. You'd then have to either capture its output (check if there was a non-integer line) or check the exit status of egrep (check out bash's PIPESTATUS variable, or its pipefail option).

Answer (score 0):

Mind, this may well not be the most efficient compared to iterating through the file with something like perl.

```
tail +2 x.x | sort -n -k 4 | head -1 | cut -f 4 | egrep "^[0-9]+$"
if [ "$?" == "0" ]
then
    echo "file is ok";
fi
```

tail +2 gives you all but the first line (since your sample has a header)
sort -n -k 4 sorts the file numerically on the 4th column, letters will rise to the top.
head -1 gives you the first line of the file
cut -f 4 gives you the 4th column, of the first line
egrep "^[0-9]+$" checks if the value is a number (integers in this case).

If egrep finds nothing, $? is 1, otherwise it's 0.

There's also:

```
if [ `tail +2 x.x | wc -l` == `tail +2 x.x | cut -f 4 | egrep "^[0-9]+$" | wc -l` ] then
    echo "file is ok";
fi
```

This will be faster, requiring two simple scans through the file, but it's not a single pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

@OP, use awk

```
awk '$4+0<=0{print "not ok";exit}' file
```